# Code is unreacheable due to scheduler while loop python flask

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to run a scheduler where in evey 1 min my index function will run.I am using flask and postgresql.But after running flask run
`app.run()` is not executed. This is the code:

```
 def index():
        connection = db.engine.connect(close_with_result=True)
        print('first')
    
        sql = text("""delete from user""")
        print('done')
        connection.execute(sql)
    
        connection = db.engine.connect(close_with_result=True)
    
        sql = text("""select * from user where name='a' or name='b'""")
        connection.execute(sql)
        connection.close()
        
 schedule.every(1).minutes.do(index)
 while True:
       schedule.run_pending()
       time.sleep(1)
    # scheduler wait for 1 second
    
 if __name__ == "__main__":
       app.run()
```

But seems like this bit of code is unreacheable:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

because of this portion of code:

```
while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
    # scheduler wait for 1 second
```

Why its not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can run a blocking loop in the same scope you use your `__main__` function.

I would say that you either create a thread to run the scheduler with the blocker loop in the background or alternatively you could use [APScheduler](https://pypi.org/project/APScheduler/).

```py
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
    

def index():
    connection = db.engine.connect(close_with_result=True)
    print('first')

    sql = text("""delete from user""")
    print('done')
    connection.execute(sql)

    connection = db.engine.connect(close_with_result=True)

    sql = text("""select * from user where name='a' or name='b'""")
    connection.execute(sql)
    connection.close()

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(func=index, trigger="interval", seconds=60)
scheduler.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: The scheduler is supposed to run every 1 min  after i run `flask run` command.But somehow the scheduler is not working as per your suggested method.But `app.run ` works

Comment: When you say it is not working, you mean it is never calling the `index` method? I would do a simple test, try to lower the seconds to 1 second, and print something on the terminal using the `index` method to verify the setup is properly done. I myself created a basic flask app with an `index` method that simply prints and a scheduler set up to 1 second, which works for me.

Comment: Yes its not calling the index method.I did all those you mentioned.May be some kind of setup problem.

Comment: Yes, hard to say without seeing the full code. Here you have the [basic example](https://gist.github.com/ArnauP/a46e82db3d5848576707414f09be983d) of code I was talking about, maybe compare it to yours or try to run it.